# Ppening an HTML file on localhost in XAMMP/apache 2.2 using subdirectories under htdocs

Tags: path, subdirectory, file-not-found, htdocs

I have a site directory for html (dreamweaver CSS3) with lots of subdirectories that contain HTML files for a number of drop down menus. They work fine where they are, but they all have menus that are JavaScript and could be kept in a separate file. So, I want to use Include. I don't want to have to FTP my files to HostGator every time I want to test the includes. I want to have this on my local machine. So, I am attempting for the first time to setup XAMMP and then run my html files (site) on localhost, so I can see what they look like before ftping everything to HostGator and putting it live.

I tried copying the main site folder to htdocs, and then copying the path to the file I want to run in front of the localhost in Firefox, but it gave me file not found:
http://localhost/xampp/PL_20080923/0-Sections/000-ComingSoon/PHPTestComingSoonNMBT-Test.html

Do I have too many subdirectories? Why isn't the file being found? It is there.

Tried this too:
http://localhost/xampp/htdocs/PL_20080923/0-Sections/000-ComingSoon/PHPTestComingSoonNMBT-Test.html

No go.

Answer (score 8):

http://localhost/ should be equivalent to xampp/htdocs/ (i.e. the same files should be accessible but served by the webserver.) This is the document root. So for example on a normal windows xampp installation http://localhost/index.html should serve c:\xampp\htdocs\index.html.

Did you try http://localhost/PL_20080923/0-Sections/000-ComingSoon/PHPTestComingSoonNMBT-Test.html ?

Comment: Rockin'!!!
Thanks for the tips!!!
Turned out that you can't have a space, at least it didn't work for me. I had to use the address you suggested, and change the name of the PL directory to PL- instead of PL_, and it worked!!! Now for the real challenge! SSI and/or PHP Includes!