# when I try to open an HTML file through `http://localhost/xampp/htdocs/index.html` it says unable to connect to localhost

Tags: html, xampp

I have installed XAMPP , there is a  `htdocs` folder and inside it  `index.html` file , 
when I try to open it in my browser through `http://localhost/xampp/htdocs/index.html` it says
unable to connect to localhost .

what is wrong ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/313128/860243

Answer (score 9):

instead of

```
 http://localhost/xampp/htdocs/index.html
```

try just

```
http://localhost/index.html
```

or if index.html is saved in a folder in htdocs then

```
http://localhost/<folder-name>/index.html
```

Answer (score 6):

`htdocs` is your default document-root directory, so you have to use `localhost/index.html` to see that html file. In other words, `localhost` is mapped to `xampp/htdocs`, so `index.html` is at `localhost` itself. You can change the location of document root by modifying `httpd.conf` and restarting the server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start your Apache Server normally you should have an xampp icon in the info-section from the taskbar, with this tool you can start the apache server as wel as the mysql database (if you need it)

Answer (score 2):

Start your XAMPP server by using:

- `{XAMPP}\xampp-control.exe`
- `{XAMPP}\apache_start.bat`

Then you have to use the URI `http://localhost/index.html` because `htdocs` is the document root of the Apache server.

If you're getting redirected to `http://localhost/xampp/*`, then `index.php` located in the `htdocs` folder is the problem because *index.php* files have a higher priority than *index.html* files.
You could temporarily rename *index.php*.

Comment: thank you ,  I do not see `apache_start.exe` but `apache_start.bat` and when run it , it waits a few seconds then says `apache is not started`  , so what is problem

Comment: @user1841718 It's *\*.bat*, of course (corrected in answer now) ;) Are there any other messages? Does the window close immediately? Please check also whether any other program is using port 80. You can accomplish this by starting the control panel (*xampp-control.exe*) and clicking on the *Netstat* button.

Comment: I have checked the port 80 and it is free but still there is a problem , the apache service in my PC can not be started , what does this mean to you ? I have tryied to start the service from control panel in services but can not be started .

Answer (score 0):

All created by user files saved in `C:\xampp\htdocs` directory by default,
so no need to type the default path in a browser window, just type
`http://localhost/yourfilename.php` or `http://localhost/yourfoldername/yourfilename.php` this will show you the content of your new page.

Answer (score 0):

Submit

```
  <br><br>  <label for="name">Name</label><br><br>  <input name="name">  <br><br>
```

Reset</ button>

Answer (score -1):

You should simply create your own folder in htdocs and save your .html and .php files in it. An example is create a folder called myNewFolder directly in htdocs. Don't put it in index.html. Then save all your.html and .php files in it like this-> "localhost/myNewFolder/myFilename.html" or "localhost/myNewFolder/myFilename.php" 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I just put an index.html file in /htdocs and type in http://127.0.0.1/index.html - and up comes the html.

Add a folder "named Forum" and type in 127.0.0.1/forum/???.???

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)